# Problems parsing JSON error while creating github repo from postman

Tags: json, github, postman

I am using the below url to create a repo in oops-project org.

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/oops-project/repos
```

I have opted for Basic Auth(username,password) and I am passing name along with description in the form-data. But the response is 400 Bad Request with the following message

```
 {
    "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
 }
```

Comment: The error indicates a wrong JSON in the request. Can you post the JSON you send to the service ?

Comment: I am sending key value pairs using form-data.  key = name value = helloworld ; key = description value = test

Comment: you might have to give the request in JSON format.

Comment: Great . that worked. I am wondering why form-data does not work. Isn't key value pair equivalent to a json body.

Comment: Apparently the API is expecting your form request to come in a JSON format. Can you please mark the answer in the answers section.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates a wrong JSON in the request.

Update: As the API is expecting in JSON format, solution is to send the request in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the body option in postman this will help you. I was facing the same issue. Please refer below Screenshot

JsonParsing issue in Postman [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsZa8.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).